# Azure blob storage - what is going on behind the scenes?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

If I understand it correctly, the Azure blob storage is a big object store, a bit like Ceph and S3?
Has there been any information regarding the architecture of this platform, which technologies it uses etc? If not, can we hazard a guess? Is it all custom?

Comment: take a look at this BUILD that covers Storage Internals: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-541

Comment: You may also find this link useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/11/20/windows-azure-storage-a-highly-available-cloud-storage-service-with-strong-consistency.aspx.